# Does promise object always need callback function?

Tags: promise

I have a requirement that I need to create a service in Angular 1 and load data with an API call which can be accessed in controllers. I earlier tried by making a API call with $http service and assigning the data to the variable / object. I then injected the service and assigned the variable / object to the controller scope variable / object.

What I observed in the controller event loop is not same as service event loop and controller scope variable / object remains undefined. Later I got a solution to work by returning a promise from the service, and calling the promise in the controller, however I'm new to promises and not able to fully absorb that when I called a promise, I had to pass the function as argument which I think is a callback for the $http API call, but I'm uncertain how it's working under the hood. Can someone explain it?

```js
//service code
this.getuserimages = function(uname) {
    console.log("Username in UserImage Service: " + uname);
    var promise = $http.get('/api/images/' + uname).then(function(response) {
        this.userimages = response.data;
        return this.userimages;
    });
    return promise;
}

// controller code        
var userimagespromise = userImageService.getuserimages($routeParams.username);
userimagespromise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.userimages = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a [Promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining).

I rewrited your code in a way that this *chain* is more clear, but the *meaning* is exactly the same:

```
$http.get('/api/images/' + uname)
.then(function(response) {
    this.userimages = response.data;
    return this.userimages;
})
.then(function(images) {
    $scope.userimages = images;
});
```

You can read this flow in this way:

- Please get me user images
- And *then*, we they will be available (=> returned from the get and passed to the *then* function), save them in a variable and return them to the *next* element of the *chain*
- And *then*, we they will be available (=> return from the previous promise), set them in the *$scope*

Please note that the entire flow is asynchronous because every Promise is "*an object representing the eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation*".

You can find more information in the [Promise documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).